# Boot.ini tab missing from msconfig in Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, msconfig

I have a machine with Windows XP that is stuck on the loading screen like in this question: [Windows XP stuck on loading screen](https://superuser.com/questions/48903/windows-xp-stuck-on-loading-screen)

The highest upvoted answer to that question seems like the next most logical step (troubleshoot drivers) because the computer can boot into safe mode.  Here's a quote of that answer in case the question gets deleted:

> If windows hangs at the loading screen it is probably hung on a custom driver. If you can get in safe mode, great, run msconfig and under "BOOT.INI" select the option "/NOGUIBOOT" under boot options and restart. You should see a list of drivers being loaded instead of the normal Windows logo. When it freezes, take note of what driver is trying to be loaded, then use google to look it up. It most likely corresponds to a third party program that you should uninstall.

I booted into safe mode but the BOOT.INI tab in msconfig is missing.
From what I recall, this is not normal functionality.

How do I restore this missing tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if your `boot.ini` is not on drive C:. Is it?

Here's an article on editing `boot.ini` manually. You can just add the `/NOGUIBOOT` switch there.

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=289022

Comment: Sir Patrick Stewart, I salute you.  The boot.ini is on another partition.

Answer (score 0):

May want to backup your registry first, but here goes:

1. Open regedit
2. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\MSConfig
3. In the right-pane, delete the value named Boot.ini  (if found)
4. Close Registry Editor and open MSCONFIG.

Comment: Navigated there.  Boot.ini entry is already missing.  Added it and restarted, no effect.