# What happens when the system is started with the /noguiboot parameter?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, data-recovery

My PC needs sometimes ridiculous amount of time to boot up, often making me worried that some kind of fatal error happened - it has happened at some occasions before.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/218150/338283) sounds like a great opportunity to see if everything's alright during the boot phase.

But since I couldn't find anything in Google, I'd like to ask you to tell: what should I *exactly* see and expect when Windows XP is started with /noguiboot parameter?

I want to know, what to expect so I can find possible errors more easily.

Comment: You should check your BIOS settings. There could be an item that's making it stuck, if you turn it off it might fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would see a blank screen, instead of the windows logo startup.  It just makes startup slightly faster.

But, **don't do it!** if you schedule a disk scan (chkdsk) you won't be able to see what is going on.  Instead, it will seem like your computer has frozen on a blank screen.